# Is the OAuth client secret sent for every API call along with the access token?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

Does the OAuth client attach the client secret along with the access token for each API call to the resource server ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you googled about the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol?

Comment: @SirMuffington Yes, I've read about OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol and also watched lectures that describe it. What I gather is that the authorization code is exchanged by the client for a access token. The client sends its client_id and secret with the authorization code to receive a access token. Then the API call to resource servers can begin.


I think the answer clicked while describing the above :). The client secret is only sent to the authorization server and not to the resource server because no one should see the client secret except the authorization server.